# Integral inequality $\left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} x f(x) dx \right| \le \left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx \right|$

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

I need to find the widest class I can for functions that obey the following inequality:

$$\left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} x f(x) dx \right| \le \left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx \right|$$

It is clear that all functions $f$ that don't change sign within the interval do:

$\displaystyle \left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} x f(x) dx \right| \le  \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \left|x\right| \left|f(x)\right| dx \le \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \left|f(x)\right| dx = \left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx \right|$,

And so do even functions:

$$\left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} x f(x) dx \right| = \left| \int\limits_{-1}^{0} x f(x) dx + \int\limits_{0}^{1} x f(x) dx \right| = 0 \le \left| \int\limits_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx \right|$$

But is there a wider class?

Comment: The inequality also holds whenever LHS is $0$ and this does not require $f$ to maintin the same sign within the interval. In fact, you can start with ANY integrable function on $(0,1)$ and construct $f$ on $(-1,0)$ so as to make the integral $0$.

Comment: Yes, but this condition is equivalent to the condition that $f$ is even: $\int \limits_{-1}^{1} x f(x) dx = \int \limits_{-1}^{1} x f^{+}(x) dx + \int \limits_{-1}^{1} x f^{-}(x) dx = \int \limits_{-1}^{1} x f^{-}(x) dx$ where $f^{\pm} = (f(x) \pm f(-x))/2$. LHS is zero means that $f^{-}$ is zero (because $x f^{-}(x)$ maintains the sign).

Comment: Your argument does not make sense. There are lots and lots of functions which are neither even nor odd for which LHS is $0$.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ for $x<0$, $0$ for $0<x<\frac 12 $ and a suitable constant for $\frac  1 2 <x<1$.

Comment: Agreed, $x f^{-} (x)$ doesn't maintain sign. Thanks, I've missed it.